# how to group by a field that has both select and count

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I am wondering how to group by a field that has both a `select count()` and `count()` statement. I know that we have to put all select fields in group by but it wont let me do so because of the second `count()` statement in the field.

```
create table C as(
select a.id, a.date_id, 
(select count(b.hits)*1.00 where b.hits >= '9')/count(b.hits) AS percent **<--error here
from A a join B b
on a.id = b.id
group by 1,2,3) with no data primary index(id);
```

This is my error:

```
[SQLState HY000] GROUP BY and WITH...BY clauses may not contain 
aggregate functions. Error Code: 3625
```

When i add a select to the second count in the third line only get 1 or 0 which is not right.

```
`((select count(b.hits)*1.00 where b.hits >= '9')/(select count(b.hits))) AS` percent
```

Do i need to do a self join instead or is there any way i can just use nested queries?

Comment: The error seems pretty clear - it looks like you are trying to group on only 2 columns, not 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you only need to group on 2 columns, not 3, plus you shouldn't need a sub-select:

```
create table C as(
select a.id, a.date_id, 
SUM(CASE WHEN b.hits >= '9' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)/COUNT(b.hits) AS percent 
from A a join B b
on a.id = b.id
group by 1,2) with no data primary index(id);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix the `group by`.  But, you can probably simplify the query as:

```
create table C as
    select a.id, a.date_id, 
           avg(b.hits >= 9) as percent 
    from A a join
         B b
         on a.id = b.id
    group by a.id, a.date_id
with no data primary index(id);
```